# How to custom rule CA1502 in visual studio project 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, fxcop, stylecop

I have a problem about custom rule for my project. My case used Microsoft Extended Design Guidline Rules and checked the rule CA1502 in Microsoft.Maintainability. Because the warning message just show when my method has cyclomatic complexity great than 25, but I want to show warning message when it great than 15. Could you make a step by step to config the problem?.

Let me know how to run MSBuild fxcop file. Please give me the script to run.

Thanks everybody,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom threshold for CA1502](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678642/custom-threshold-for-ca1502)

Comment: Sorry, but I don''t know how to do that. Could you give me a detail. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you let me know how to intergrate fxcop settings file into visual studio project. Thanks